# Magento-CE-2.3.0-2018-11-27-10-23-08 CSS

Tags: css, magento2.3, installation, http-error-500

I have installed the above version of Magento 2 (no sample data) onto my 1an1 hosting site. No errors on installation however, the stylesheets are not loading. I've tried a few suggestions to fix via here and the magento forum but most if not all answers use terminal console or similar for the fixes for which I do not have access to.

When I look in the pub/static folder there are no css files. I'm not sure if this is a rewrite issue or not. pub folder has been set with file permissions 777 via filezilla ftp.

I did not use the composer as I am really not sure how to use this under a hosted site.

I am also getting an Internal Server error 500 when trying to access the admin area

Do I need to copy the css files to the static folder or elsewhere ?

This lack of css etc seems to be a common problem with the installation but I have NO idea how to fix this on 1and1. Any help would be appreciated however please keep it simple for me please.

Versions : PHP 7.2 SQL 5.7

Kind Regards Kate
[image: Root Homepage]

[image: Internal server error on admin login]

Comment: I assume you did not install Magento using cPanel

Comment: What error do you get when trying to access admin backend can you check it in the apache logs?

Comment: have you assigned your magento directory's file system owner to your server's apache or www-data group, you can follow https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Comment: Magefms, 1and1 do not have the app for Magento 2 it's 1.9 so no it wasn't installed via the cpanel

Comment: I can't seem to get to the apache logs sorry Daniel